# FIND and LEN functiosS did not work in my excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I watched a training video on excel FIND and LEN functions and I followed the same thing that was done on the video but I did not get the desired

I typed the FIND function =FIND(" ",C2) in my attached excel file and was expecting it to show me the position of the spaces in the cell but it returned an error.

I typed =LEN(C3) and was expecting it to return the number of characters in the cell which is 19 but it returned 16.

[image]

How do I correct this?

Comment: The values in column C are numbers (date value with time) `=INT(C2)` will return the date value (you may need to format the cell as date). `=MOD(C2,1)` will return the time only (which you may need to format as time).

Comment: Dates are integers starting from January 1st 1900 being `1`. Time is a fraction of the day (a day equals 1, an hour 1/24, a minute equals 1/24/60, etc

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that "dates" in Excel are a very particular way of looking at integer values in the case of dates and real numbers in the case of date&time.

If you import this small CSV file into Excel you will see how it works:

```
Len,Type,"Date formatted to type"
=LEN(C2),string,"11/02/2024"
=LEN(C3),date,=TODAY()
=LEN(C4),number,45333
=LEN(C5),string,"11/02/2024 12:34"
=LEN(C6),date,=NOW()
=LEN(C7),number,45333.5236111111
```

They might be displayed as strings but they are real numbers underneath that facade so you can't use string matches on them. 16 is the length of a double precision floating point number in Excel and 5 is the typical length of a date. It isn't especially helpful to novices. The split date and time apart from a datetime take the integer part and the fractional part of a day separately.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost never a good approach, but it will give you the result you expected.

You can treat the date as text within the formula by adding the `TEXT` formula:

```
=LEN(TEXT(A3,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"))

=FIND(" ",TEXT(A3,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"))
```

[image]